# How do I build a query to select master and last detail (max(Id)) with LiNQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How do I write a LiNQ to Entities query like the one in the answer of the following question:

[SQL Select From Master - Detail Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418154/sql-select-from-master-detail-tables)

I would like to leverage the existing navigating properties existent in my model (imported database to an Entity Framework EDMX).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the assumptions AarronLS presented, you'd also need a navigation property from Brands to Models.

```
var modelsAndBrandsFlattened = from brand in db.Brands
                               let latestModel = brand.Models.Last()
                               select new {
                                   brand.Brand,
                                   brand.BrandId,
                                   latestModel.Model,                                       
                                   latestModel.ModelId
                                }
```

Comment: +1 but should it be `brand.Models.OrderBy(m.detId).Last()` otherwise it is a bit of a gamble of which one will be last I think since even with clustered index, the order of rows is not guaranteed if you don't have an order by.

Comment: Apparently "Last()" isn't supported by Linq to Entities. It seems like it really can't translate to a store query. If I'm using Linq to Objects then this will work. However, I had to query all details records from the database first. Hopefully there is a way to retrieve only what I really need. Thanks.

Comment: Based on what I have so far, I also tried "OrderBy(Id).First()", "OrderBy(Id).FirstOrDefault". No lucky. Tried "OrderBy(Id).Take(1)" but this seems to be translated as "First". So, also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a navigation property from Model to the Parent Brand called `Brand`, and `db` is your DbContext

```
var modelsAndBrandsFlattened = db.Models.Select(m => new {
        m.Brand.Brand,
        m.Model,
        m.Brand.BrandId,
        m.ModelId
    });
```

Comment: This is close to what I'm doing. However, I don't want all the details. For each master I want only the last inserted detail which is the one with the highest Id. I tried "m.Brand.Last()" but this can't be translated to a store query.